# SoapUI : Mocking Service

Tags: soapui

I have a requirement where I need to add a new method to existing web service. That I have mocked using SOAPUI mocking responses feature. But for other methods I want the request to direct to some other endpoint(where implementation of already existing).

Regards,
Lalit Kumar

Answer (score 0):

So in the client application, you need to have separate endpoints for each method.  And you only point to your mockserver for the new method.

Another possibility would be to configure the SoapUI mockservice to handle all requests, and except for the new method, to call the original backend. i.e. it would be a proxy for the old services.  That would likely require scripting.